# Webpack adds every assets to root diretory

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to implement SSR using React (create-react-app) and Firebase. To do so, I'm currently working on my webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = [{
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.css$/i, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
            {test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|otf)$/i, loader: 'file-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'public/bundle.js',
        path: __dirname
    }
}];
```

The webpack works fine without any errors (some size limit warnings, but from what I've read online I can ignore them). Anyways somehow it's adding every single asset to my root folder (not even inside of my directory), which is kind of ugly and confusing. - **How can I change the output target of these assets?**

Answer (score 0):

Change your `output` to

```
output: {
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/assets')
}
```

This will put your `bundle.js` in the `dist/assets/js` directory inside your project's root.

As another example, if you want your `bundle.js` in `public/js` folder in your project's root, configure it like this

```
output: {
    filename: 'js/bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
}
```

If you leave out the `path` option entirely, it'll default to the `dist` directory.

Or refer [this Webpack documentation page](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpath) and adjust the values accordingly.

Also, don't forget to import the `path` module

```
const path = require('path');
```